# Use PyDrive on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, pydrive

I'm trying to use PyDrive on Heroku.
My code is as follows.

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
GoogleAuth.DEFAULT_SETTINGS['client_config_file'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'client_secrets.json')
```

However, the heroku console returned "No such file or directory: '/app/client_secrets.json'".
Through `heroku run bash` command, I confirmed that '/app/client_secrets.json' surely existed.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this first

```
gauth = GoogleAuth()
```

then

```
GoogleAuth.DEFAULT_SETTINGS['client_config_file'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'client_secrets.json')
gauth.LoadCredentials()
```

Hope this is helpful to you.